# MongoDB connection error, sockets closed when running tests with mocha in watch mode. NODE.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm building a rating module that would help me rate different documents. One of the features is that you can only rate existing models. So if you have 3 models: ['User', 'Product', 'Company'] there should be an attribute called `modelName` that should only receive existing models. For that i've built this test:

```
import app from '../..'
import Rating from './rating.model'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

describe('Rating Model', () => {

  after(done => {
    mongoose.disconnect(() => {
      mongoose.models = {}
      mongoose.modelSchemas = {}
      done()
    })
  })

  describe('documentType', () => {

    it('fails on attempt to set a non existant model name', () => {
      const modelNames = mongoose.modelNames()
      console.log(modelNames)
    })

  })
})
```

The after function have to disconnect mongoose when finishing all the tests so it doesn't fails with a 
`cannot overwrite existing model`.

If i don't disconnect mongoose it will fail with a
`MongoDB connection error: Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.`

If i don't import app it will show me only the imported model `Rating`

But with all this set, it fails with a
`MongoDB connection error: MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed`

My app.js:

```
/**
 * Main application file
 */

'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config/environment');
var http = require('http');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
  process.exit(-1);
});

// Populate databases with sample data
if (config.seedDB) { require('./config/seed'); }

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Start server
function startServer() {
  server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
  });
}

if (!module.parent.parent) { // <-- this is used to don't start again when using integration tests.
  setImmediate(startServer);
}


// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app
```

Any help? i need to use the watch option in mocha so it keeps reloading after i save.